# Cannot use tweepy.api.search_full_archive (Python)

Tags: api, twitter, python-requests, twitterapi-python

I have been trying to use the command search_full_archive as follows:

```
data = []
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive, enviroment_name = 'Understanding', query = '((PAN AND Nuevo León) OR (Partido Accion Nacional AND Nuevo León) OR (PAN AND Monterrey) OR (Partido Acción Nacional AND Monterrey))', fromDate = '202105060000', toDate = '20210706').items(10)
    data.append(user._json)
```

To get ten tweets according query between 06-May-2021 and 06-Jul-2021 using the Dev Enviroment with name Understanding but I get nothing but the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-81-a0a875f90f3a>", line 2
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive, enviroment_name = 'Understanding', query = '((PAN AND Nuevo León) OR
 (Partido Accion Nacional AND Nuevo León) OR (PAN AND Monterrey) OR
 (Partido Acción Nacional AND Monterrey))', fromDate = '202105060000',
 toDate = '202107060000').items(10)
                   ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just do not understand why I have a syntax error, hope you can help me. I've been dealing with this for a while. PD. Also I tried to put the dates like this (fromDate = b_timestamp, toDate = e_timestamp):

```
b_string = "06/05/2021"
e_string = "06/07/2021"
b_element = datetime.datetime.strptime(b_string,"%d/%m/%Y")
b_tuple = b_element.timetuple()
b_timestamp = time.mktime(b_tuple)
e_element = datetime.datetime.strptime(e_string,"%d/%m/%Y")
e_tuple = e_element.timetuple()
e_timestamp = time.mktime(e_tuple)
```

Comment: It seems that recently the function search_full_archive change a little bit, according the documentation: Help on method search_full_archive in module tweepy.api:

search_full_archive(label, query, **kwargs) method of tweepy.api.API instance
 search_full_archive(label, query, *, tag, fromDate, toDate, maxResults, next) with label as the (case-sensitive) label associated with your search developer environment.